# Adding squared numbers to find magnitude

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm using Pythagoras' Theorem to try and work out the magnitude of a vector:

> vector = (-3, 7)
>
> magnitude = $\sqrt{ -3^2 +7^2 }$
>
> magnitude = $\sqrt{ -9 + 49 }$

Now here's the thing, I would then go:

> magnitude = $\sqrt{ 40 }$

but the text book goes

> magnitude = $\sqrt{ -3^2 + 7^2 }$ = $\sqrt{ 58 }$

I mean where does that 58 come from? Where?

Comment: Note that $(-3)^2=9\ne -9.$

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz I'd have thought that, but according to the google calculator it's -9?

Comment: Put -3 in parenthesis then square. $-3^2=-9 \neq (-3)^2=9$

Comment: It is because of the priority in calculations. If you write $-3^2$ the calculator computes first the square and then changes sign. But you need to write $(-3)^2$ to get the square of $-3.$

Comment: ohhhhhhhh silly me

Comment: So when I put -3^2 into the calculator it is literally working out 3^2 ?

Comment: No. If you put $-3^2$ the calculator computes $3^2=9$ first and then changes sign, that is, $-9.$ It is different from $(-3)^2.$ The calculator computes $(-3)\cdot (-3)=9.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector $(a,b)$ its magnitude is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Here $a=-3$ and $b=7$ so $a^2+b^2$=$(-3)^2+7^2=58$   (be careful, $(-3)^2\neq -3^2$
    !!)

Therefore the magnitude is $\sqrt{(-3)^2+7^2}=\sqrt{58}$

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was to use $-3^2=-9$ instead of $(-3)^2=+9$.